# How much damage does each tool do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I read on the wiki that a diamond shovel does as much damage as a wooden sword.

This lead me to wonder how much damage each tool does.

What I'd like to know is the specific values that each tool at each tier does (wooden, stone etc.) including swords.

Half a heart is equal to one damage, so a whole heart is two damage.

The reason I want to know is in case I get caught in a fight without a sword, I'll know which of my tools is going to offer me the best chance of surviving.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The damage charts can be located [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Weapons) but I cropped them for you.

> Mobs' health is measured in 'hearts', just like the player's. Chickens
> have 2 hearts; sheep have 4; cows, squids and pigs have 5; spiders/cave spiders
> have 8; skeletons, creepers, blazes, tamed wolves zombie pigmen, and zombies
> have 10; Ghasts have only 5 hearts. Wild wolves have
> 4 hearts. Slimes and magma cubes react differently to damage. Their
> health depends on their size.

[image]

[image]

Any tool not listed above (hoe's, shears etc.) will do normal "fist" damage when used.

Critical [hits are as following](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Critical_hits):

[image]

Comment: is this answer still up do date?

Comment: @Gigala no, as of 1.9

Comment: @ElliotA. Yeahh its outdated again i assume

Answer (score 2):

In 1.8 or earlier versions, tool damage bonuses are:

- Swords (4 for wooden or golden, +1 for stone, +2 for iron, +3 for diamond)
- Axes (3 for wooden or golden, +1 for stone, +2 for iron, +3 for diamond)
- Pickaxes (2 for wooden or golden, +1 for stone, +2 for iron, +3 for diamond)
- Spades (1 for wooden or golden, +1 for stone, +2 for iron, +3 for diamond)
- Hoes (N/A)

Note: They also receive +1 from initial attack strength.

So for a diamond sword you will deal 4 hearts of damage if the hit is not critical.
Note that critical hits deal +50% more damage than usual ones.

In 1.9, tools also have a cooldown, which prevents you from hitting too often (even if the cooldown is short; [see here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Attack_critical) for more details.)
Also, axes deal +2 damage than previous versions, more than swords, but the cooldown for them is big, and they are damaged 2 durability points per hit, rather than swords. Except for axes, tool damages are the same as in 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

### Java Edition 1.9 or later:

- None: 1
- Wooden Sword: 4, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Golden Sword: 4, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Stone Sword: 5, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Iron Sword: 6, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Diamond Sword: 7, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Netherite Sword (1.16 or later): 8, cooldown of 0.63 seconds
- Wooden Axe: 7, cooldown of 1.25 seconds
- Golden Axe: 7, cooldown of 1 second
- Stone Axe: 9, cooldown of 1.25 seconds
- Iron Axe: 9, cooldown of 1.11 seconds
- Diamond Axe: 9, cooldown of 1 second
- Netherite Axe (1.16 or later): 10, cooldown of 1 second
- Wooden Pickaxe: 2, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Golden Pickaxe: 2, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Stone Pickaxe: 3, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Iron Pickaxe: 4, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Diamond Pickaxe: 5, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Netherite Pickaxe (1.16 or later): 6, cooldown of 0.83 seconds
- Wooden Shovel: 2.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Golden Shovel: 2.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Stone Shovel: 3.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Iron Shovel: 4.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Diamond Shovel: 5.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Netherite Shovel (1.16 or later): 6.5, cooldown of 1 second
- Wooden Hoe: 1, cooldown of 1 second
- Golden Hoe: 1, cooldown of 1 second
- Stone Hoe: 1, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Iron Hoe: 1, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Diamond Hoe: 1, cooldown of 0.25 seconds
- Netherite Hoe (1.16 or later): 1, cooldown of 0.25 seconds
- Trident: 9, cooldown of 0.91 seconds

### Java Edition 1.8 or earlier or Bedrock Edition

- None: 2
- Wooden Sword: 5
- Golden Sword: 5
- Stone Sword: 6
- Iron Sword: 7
- Diamond Sword: 8
- Netherite Sword (Bedrock Edition): 9
- Wooden Axe: 4
- Golden Axe: 4
- Stone Axe: 5
- Iron Axe: 6
- Diamond Axe: 7
- Netherite Axe (Bedrock Edition): 8
- Wooden Pickaxe: 2
- Golden Pickaxe: 2
- Stone Pickaxe: 3
- Iron Pickaxe: 4
- Diamond Pickaxe: 5
- Netherite Pickaxe (Bedrock Edition): 6
- Wooden Shovel: 2
- Golden Shovel: 2
- Stone Shovel: 3
- Iron Shovel: 4
- Diamond Shovel: 5
- Netherite Shovel (Bedrock Edition): 6
- Wooden Hoe: 2
- Golden Hoe: 2
- Stone Hoe: 3
- Iron Hoe: 4
- Diamond Hoe: 5
- Netherite Hoe: 6
- Trident (Bedrock Edition): 9

### Java Edition Combat Test 8c

- None: 2
- Wooden Sword: 4, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Golden Sword: 4, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Stone Sword, 4, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Iron Sword: 5, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Diamond Sword: 6, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Netherite sword: 7, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Wooden Axe: 5, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Golden Axe: 5, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Stone Axe: 5, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Iron Axe 6, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Diamond Axe: 7, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Netherite Axe: 8, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Wooden Pickaxe: 3, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Golden Pickaxe: 3, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Stone Pickaxe: 3, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Iron Pickaxe: 4, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Diamond Pickaxe: 5, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Netherite Pickaxe: 6, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Wooden Shovel: 2, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Golden Shovel: 2, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Stone Shovel: 2, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Iron Shovel: 3, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Diamond Shovel: 4, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Netherite Shovel: 5, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Wooden Hoe: 2, cooldown of 0.5 seconds
- Golden Hoe: 2, cooldown of 0.29 seconds
- Stone Hoe: 2, cooldown of 0.4 seconds
- Iron Hoe: 3, cooldown of 0.33 seconds
- Diamond Hoe: 3, cooldown of 0.29 seconds
- Netherite Hoe: 4, cooldown of 0.29 seconds
- Trident: 7, cooldown of 0.5 seconds

### Reach in Java Edition Combat Test 8c

- Sword: 3
- Axe: 2.5
- Pickaxe: 2.5
- Shovel: 2.5
- Hoe: 2.5